# JS D3 textPath isn't displayed

Tags: javascript, text, svg, path, d3.js

i have the code below and wonder, why the textpath isn't displayed? Can anyone help?

```
var areas = svg.append("g").selectAll("path")
    .data(chord.groups)
    .enter().append("path")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return fill(d.index); })
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("id", function(d, i) { return "group" + i; })
    .attr("d", d3.svg.arc().innerRadius(innerRadius).outerRadius(outerRadius))
    .on("mouseover", fade(.1))
    .on("mouseout", fade(1));

svg.selectAll(".bar").append("text")
    .style("font-size", "10px")
    .attr("fill", "black")
.append("textPath")
    .attr("x", 8)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("fill", "#ff00ff")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d, i) { return "#group" + i; })
    .text("Textexample");
```

Thank you very much!
Benjamin

Comment: The path for a textpath needs to be defined in the `defs` section IIRC.

Comment: @Lars: No, it doesn't.

Comment: You should paste the generated svg html as most likely the generated svg html is bad as I am assuming that is what my issue is right now as I keep copying an example and then looking back to my generated html...have you copy/pasted the generated html into a document to see if it works with no javascript.

Comment: yup, I easily solved mine not showing up by copying the svg html and using that, debugging that and getting my javascript to generate it correctly