# Links and textPaths in D3 cluster layout

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, hierarchy

My question is very similar to [JS D3 textPath isn't displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164348/js-d3-textpath-isnt-displayed)

The one difference is I want to attach the json that comes back to the links not just the nodes(well, for every node that has a link going to it's parent, I want that link to have the same json)...and ideally, I actually want to add a line from the root node out to the left as well going nowhere.

Then, I basically want to have text in the middle of my link and following the link line would be nice but not absolutely necessary.

My current non-working code is(and I am not sure, but do I need to add an id element to each link? but for to do so I would need the json!!!! plus I need the json to retrieve the text for each link as well) and then I think I use the id in the textPath to refer back to the path if I am not mistaken, right?

```
var width = $("#graph").width(),
    height = 200;

var cluster = d3.layout.cluster()
    .size([height, width - 160]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
var myDiv = document.getElementById('graph');

var svg = d3.select(myDiv).append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(40,0)");

d3.json("/datastreams/json/${_encoded}", function(error, root) {
  var nodes = cluster.nodes(root),
      links = cluster.links(nodes);

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(links)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })

  link.append("text")
     .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.selected ? "16px" : "10px"; })
     .style("font-weight", function(d) { return d.selected ? "bold" : ""; })
     .text(function(d) { return "SSSS="+d.name; });

  node.append("circle")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.selected ? 10 : 4.5; });

  var refs = node.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return d.root ? "start" : "end"; });

  var text = refs.append("text")
  .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.root ? 8 : -8; })
  .attr("dy", -4)
  .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.root ? "start" : "end"; });

  text.append("tspan")
     .style("font-size", function(d) { return d.selected ? "16px" : "10px"; })
     .style("font-weight", function(d) { return d.selected ? "bold" : ""; })
     .style("fill", function(d) { return "blue"; })
     .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

ah, there we go as this seems to be working(well, I am not fully done but have it very close to what I want).

```
  var textPath = path.each(function(l){
    var aref = theG.append("a")
        .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://databus.nrel.gov" });
    var text = aref.append("text")
          .style("fill", function(d) { return "blue"; });
    var textPath = text.append("textPath")
            .attr("startOffset", "50%")
            .attr("xlink:href", "#path"+l.target.name)
            .text("insert");

    var aref2 = theG.append("a")
    .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://databus.nrel.gov" });
  var text2 = aref2.append("text")
    .style("fill", function(d) { return "blue"; });
  var textPath2 = text2.append("textPath")
    .attr("startOffset", "60%")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#path"+l.target.name)
    .text("delete");
  });
```